# looking for a better way to write a command piping tr in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I was just wondering if there is anyway to do this command more efficiently than the way I did. If there is please let me know!

```
cat logfile | tr '[' '(' | tr '{' '(' | tr ']' ')' | tr '}' ')'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tr` works by replacing characters (or regular expressions) but handles only one operation per invocation

`sed` may be more suited to achieve what you want. It can handle multiple operations per invocation

try

```
sed -e 's/\[/(/g' -e 's/{/(/g' -e 's/\]/)/g' -e 's/}/)/g' catfile
```

you can even edit the input file with the `-i` switch to sed

```
sed -i -e 's/\[/(/g' -e 's/{/(/g' -e 's/\]/)/g' -e 's/}/)/g' catfile
```

Note:

`[` indicates the beginning of a regular expression, so it has to be escaped by a backslash to make sed search and replace the string literal `[`

Comment: And you can combine them all into a single `y` command in `sed`.

Comment: @karakfa, time for me to rtfm for `tr`, thanks! 
@Barmar, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can combine all translations into one

```
tr '[]{}' '()()'
```